# How to save files from C to browser storage with emscripten

Tags: emscripten

The [game engine](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev) that I'm using to run my [game](http://skyturns.se) in the browser runs lua and from my game i save files using normal fopen / write / fclose. The engine C/C++ code is compiled to JS through emscripten. What is a good way to get these file writes to end up in local storage, or some other in browser cache location? I have searched the web and looked at the documentation but information is very sparse, I have not found any clear answers to how this is supposed to work.

A previous contributor to the game engine added a js library to the emscripten build, that would override `fclose` to call back to javascript. But this fclose override does not seem to get called anymore, it is not included in the final .js file at all.

Comment: localStorage has 5-10MB limit though. Is it what you want?

Comment: hmm, what are my alternatives? IndexedDB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Emscripten Filesystem API covers your case using IndexedDB.

Here is the [Filesystem API overview](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html#file-system-overview). It has four types:

1. `MEMFS`: A volatile, in-memory storage. This is the default filesystem type which is mounted at `/` at runtime.
2. `NODEFS`: This uses node.js fs api, which is not your case.
3. `IDBFS`: This makes use of IndexedDB and you may use it for offline storage.
4. `WORKERFS`: This is intended to be used inside of a worker.

You can use `IDBFS` with Emscripten's own FS API (This is JavaScript-side API though). You need to mount it first in order to use it. You can achieve it by using [`FS.mkdir`,`FS.mount`, and `FS.syncfs`](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#FS.syncfs). Here is a rough example in C:

```c
#include <emscripten.h>
    
int main() {
    // EM_ASM is a macro to call in-line JavaScript code.
    EM_ASM(
        // Make a directory other than '/'
        FS.mkdir('/offline');
        // Then mount with IDBFS type
        FS.mount(IDBFS, {}, '/offline');

        // Then sync
        FS.syncfs(true, function (err) {
            // Error
        });
    );

    // Use fopen / write / fclose in C here.
    int off_file = fopen("/offline/any_file");
    ...

    // Don't forget to sync to make sure you store it to IndexedDB
    EM_ASM(
        FS.syncfs(function (err) {
            // Error
        });
    );
}
```

[Here is a more detailed example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/main/test/fs/test_idbfs_sync.c) from Emscripten repository.

Comment: So the javascript in the EM_ASM macro is somehow kept through the whole build, llvm and everything? The game engine has a cmake build system, and the last command is just emcc on the whole engine.so file, so just worried that the EM_ASM might get lost somewhere along the way. If not this looks really good - there is already a fclose hook in the native code I could use to sync.

Comment: Can I otherwise just run this stuff from the javascript side? Mount a dir to which I know the game will write stuff, sync, then run main, wait for things to save in the game, and call sync again?

Comment: At least you don't need to worry about EM_ASM being lost. Because not only you call `emcc` but you have to also build the whole project in the Emscripten environment. To say, you must use `emconfigure cmake .` command instead of `cmake .`. [Take a look at Emscripten build process docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html). You will get into a trouble if you ignore `emconfigure` and `emmake` because WebAssembly is a very different environment. For example, it currently 32-bits only.

Comment: You can call them in JavaScript however, that JS code must be one of input file of `emcc` command with `--pre-js` and `--post-js` build options. If you don't like `EM_ASM` being a part of your original functions, there is [`EM_JS` option](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-javascript-from-native) that converts a whole C/C++ function to JS, allowing it to be separate `.c` file.

Comment: The engine uses cmake with an emscripten toolchain file, I have no idea how it works unfortunately. And its a big project, I'm not really competent enough to start doing it differently. But you mean I have to do it from `--post-js` because these file system functions are not exposed outside? What about if I use `EXPORT_RUNTIME_FUNCTIONS` or similar? I guess I could add two functions to `Module` through `--post-js`, something like `Module["mountIDBFSdir"] = function(dir) ...` and `Module["syncfs"] = function(callback) { FS.syncfs(true, callback) }`. What do you think about that?

Comment: I meant `EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS` not functions :)

Comment: Hey, I got it to work! Using the `--post-js` and adding those two functions. Just a minor thing, the second `FS.syncfs` should not have argument true, then all files just disappeared. I'll try to edit your code. Thanks!

Comment: I glad to hear it works :) As you guessed adding functions field to `Module` is the right way to work. When you compile with `emcc`, you will get a auto-generated JS file which comes from a JS template called [`preamble.js`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/preamble.js) and `preamble.js` is where `Module` object is declared and the runtime is initiated (and  where `EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS` are attached to `Module`).

Comment: `--post-js` option is to add your own JS code concatenated after `preamble.js`, `--pre-js` for adding code before `preamble.js`. For more advanced usage with Emscripten, you may hack around `Module`. In that case you probably want to look at the source code of  `preamble.js` (or the generated JS code by `emcc`) to see what happen happens to the runtime.