# How can I use MEMFS with Emscripten and Wasm?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I want to create a simple file write/read program with Emscripten and Webassembly.
I want to choose a file from browser, copy it and download new copy. This is just for trial.
I did a lot of research but I couldn't. Can anyone help me?
This is my C++ code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void copyFile(char* filePath, char* savePath)
{
    std::cout << "\nstarted!\n";

    std::ifstream src(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream dest(savePath, std::ios::binary);

    std::cout << "\ncreated!\n";

    dest << src.rdbuf();

    std::cout << "\ncopied!\n";

    src.close();
    dest.close();

    std::cout << "\nfinished!\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "\nmain started!\n";

    std::cout << argv[1];
    std::cout << argv[2];

    copyFile(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Wasm still doesn't violate the sandbox. You can save a file virtually in the sandbox, but you can't write to the user's actual filesystem.

Comment: Yes but I think we can upload and download files to sandbox.

Comment: Depends greatly on what you mean by "upload" and "download". My last brush with WASM was when I implemented battery save files for the WASM port of the SNES9x Super Nintendo console emulator a couple of years ago. So, with the caveat that this knowledge is potentially outdated... When it comes to files, WASM gives you a virtual filesystem backed by localStorage that you can save to/retrieve from. But this is a virtual filesystem, not a real one: you don't actually have access to the user's actual filesystem as that would fundamentally violate the browser's security model. Now, it is possible..

Comment: ...[cont'd] in the browser to *literally* upload a file, to a server, using an HTML input tag of type "file". But you can't read/write it from C++ in WASM, you can only initiate a dialog in JS for the user to select a file to upload to some URL. You could then modify the file *on the server* and fetch a modified version back to the client. A clever person could probably even figure out a way to stream it back and forth over a websocket. But we're way, waaaay beyond the realm of what you're suggesting with the code you posted. What you seem to be wanting simply isn't possible.

Comment: You can save a file to the virtual filesystem, and retrieve it from there, but it's just localStorage: you don't actually save the file to a location on the filesystem and if the user clears their browser cache it's gone.

Comment: Here's the repository https://github.com/jasmith79/xnes/tree/saves

Comment: Thanks for comments and explanations. And I know many of them. If you review this site, I can explain my purpose a little better. https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-persist-data
And this is an example https://github.com/munshkr/emscripten-fs-example
I am a beginner in Emscripten and Javascript. So I couldn't adapt.

Comment: Yeah, none of that changes anything I said above. You couldn't adapt it because, again, *you can't do that*. You just can't. The browser will give you a fake filesystem so you can save and retrieve "files" that your app creates, but it won't let you touch the real one. You can't do it in JS, and you can't do it in WASM. Period. Do you *want* arbitrary websites to be able to write to your filesystem?

Comment: You didn't understand me. Or I can't explain. I don't want access files on my device directly. Look at this: https://github.com/InfiniBrains/gdcm-js. They compiled GDCM library with Emscripten toolchain and created an example app: https://infinibrains.github.io/gdcm-js/ I want to do an app like this. But of course my C++ codes and algorithms are different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617194/how-to-save-files-from-c-to-browser-storage-with-emscripten

Comment: I saw this but I want to use MEMFS. This topic is about IDBFS.

Comment: But MEMFS is completely ephemeral, your code as written won't actually *do* anything. You say you want the user to choose a file to copy, which is completely meaningless in this context. A file from where? You don't have any access to the user's files and you aren't making any requests.  You're accessing argv to get a source and destination, how is that being populated? This isn't being called from a terminal. How is the *user* supposed to understand the layout of the virtual file system WASM provides?  *None of this makes any sense*. Please edit your question into a form that is answerable.